# Thymeleaf - Conditional Attributes only showing for a split second in html

Tags: html, spring, attributes, conditional-statements, thymeleaf

i am working on a spring web application. i tried to write a function that checks whether if the entered password is correct.
this is the code from my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView loginUser(@ModelAttribute User user) throws FileNotFoundException {
    if (patient.getPasswort().equals(patient.getPasswortConfirm())) {
        Service.login(user);
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("mainpage");
        modelAndView.addObject("user", user);
        return modelAndView;
    } else {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("login");
        modelAndView.addObject("wrongpw", true);
        return modelAndView;
    }

}
```

this is the code from the html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="image/favicon.ico" />
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
<script src="lib/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
<div id="menuebg"></div>


<p th:if="${wrongpw}"><font color="red">Password is wrong</font></p>
<div id="menue">
 <form action="01erstellen" method="post"  th:object="${patient}">
  <table border="0px">
    <tr height="20px">
<td>Name: <input th:field="*{nachname}" onchange="nameLive();"   type="text" id="txtName" value="" />
</td>
</tr>

<tr height="20px">
<td>Vorname: <input th:field="*{vorname}" onchange="vornameLive();" type="text" id="txtVorname" value="" />
</td>
</tr>

<tr height="20px">
<td>Email: <input th:field="*{email}" type="text" />
 </td>
 </tr>

 <tr height="20px">
 <td><label for="gebdat"> Geburtsdatum: <input th:field="*{geburtstag}" type="date" id="gebdat" />
</label></td>
</tr>

<tr height="20px">
<td><label for="passwd">Passwort: <input th:field="*{passwort}" type="password" id="passwd" size="20" maxlength="40" />
</label></td>
</tr>

<tr height="20px">
<td><label for="passwd-confirm">Wiederholen: <input th:field="*{passwortConfirm}"
                                                               type="password" id="passwd-confirm" size="20" maxlength="40" />
</label></td>
</tr>

<tr height="20px">
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr height="20px">
<td>
<br/>
<input id="btn-send" type="submit" value="Finish" />
</td>
</tr>

<tr height="20px">
<td></td>
</tr>

</table>

</form>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

my problem is that if i type in a wrong password the text only shows for a split second an then disappears.
can someone help me?
thank you!

Comment: Nothing wrong with what you posted so far, can you show us your full @RequestMapping code and the full view?

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public ModelAndView loginUser(@ModelAttribute User user) throws FileNotFoundException {

  if (patient.getPasswort().equals(patient.getPasswortConfirm())) {
   Service.login(user);
   ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("mainpage");
   modelAndView.addObject("user", user);
   return modelAndView;
  } else {
   ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("login");
   modelAndView.addObject("wrongpw", true);
   return modelAndView;
  }

 }

Comment: sorry that looks terrible :(

Comment: Edit your original post rather than as a comment

Comment: i noticed that the error message disappears when the page finished loading

Comment: The problem probably is in your view, can you please post it?

Comment: Yes. HTML content doesn't just disappear without a redirect or some javascript.

Comment: You have an error in your html (`<font>` tag is not closing properly). I'm pretty sure the effect has something to do with your css and/or javascript (that applies the effect that you are experiencing).

Comment: i removed the font tag but it still disappears after loading :(

Comment: To find the source of error: remove all the css (external as well as local) - test if the error occurs - and continue (if it still occurs) add the css again, remove all the javascript. If it still occurs remove both (css and js).

Comment: thanks for the advice guys. i removed the css file and it worked. i am going to search the error in it now

Comment: it working now, thanks!